# Successfully installed dlib still dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA returning false

Tags: face-recognition, dlib

I am trying to use GPU for @ageitgey face recognition api
I installed and compiled dlib successfully during installation of dlib I got
Found CUDA: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1 (found suitable version "10.1", minimum required is "7.5")
-- Looking for cuDNN install...
-- Found cuDNN: C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.1/lib/x64/cudnn.lib
-- Building a CUDA test project to see if your compiler is compatible with CUDA...
-- Checking if you have the right version of cuDNN installed.
-- Enabling CUDA support for dlib.  DLIB WILL USE CUDA
-- C++11 activated.
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done

BUT now when I am running
import dlib
print(dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA)
in SPYDER I am getting FALSE
please help

### Expected Behavior

I expected (dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA) to return TRUE
I expected CNN face detector model to run on GPU

### Current Behavior

dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA is returning false
CNN based face detector is taking whole CPU and RAM
I also checked gpu usage by using nvidia-smi but it was not showing any usage
cuda.get_num_devices()   returns 1

### Steps to Reproduce

install dlib https://github.com/davisking/dlib
install cuda toolkit and other dependecies
Run this
https://github.com/davisking/dlib

dlib version dlib==19.18.99
dlib: https://github.com/davisking/dlib
I am working on Windows 10 64 bit
I am using SPYDER

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps to resolve this issue

1. Uninstall face_recognition and dlib

*pip uninstall  dlib face_recognition*

2. reinstalled dlib(compiled with cuda)

*python setup.py install*

3. check again

*import dlib*

*dlib.DLIB_USE_CUDA*

True